# Rewrite the feasible set of a linear programming problem

Tags: linear-programming

Consider a $K\times 1$ vector $x$ and define
$$
\mathcal{X}\equiv\{x\in \mathbb{R}^K: A*x\leq b\}
$$
where $A$ is a $J\times K$ matrix containing known real scalars and $b$ is a $J\times 1$ vector containing known real scalars.

Is it correct to say that
$$
\mathcal{X}\equiv [\min_{x\in \mathcal{X}} x_1, \max_{x\in \mathcal{X}} x_1]\times [\min_{x\in \mathcal{X}} x_2, \max_{x\in \mathcal{X}} x_2]\times ...\times [\min_{x\in \mathcal{X}} x_K, \max_{x\in \mathcal{X}} x_K]
$$
where "$\times$" denotes Cartesian product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are suggesting the the feasible region must be rectangular but this is not true.

For example, we have have $x \ge 0, y \ge 0, x+y \le 1$. The feasible region is triangular.

It is not equal to $[0,1] \times [0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks. Is it correct to say that by computing $[\min_{x\in \mathcal{X}} x_k, \max_{x\in \mathcal{X}} x_k]$ I only get the projection of the feasible set on the $k$-th dimension?

Comment: yes, that is the projection.